# apps in the startup menu of task manager doesn't exist in startup menu, why?

Tags: windows-10, boot

< OS env :  WIN10 >

[1\This is apps in the startup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntDaZ.jpg)

[2\This is so called where auto-start apps(lnk files) should be nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDw9b.jpg)

question : 
why they don't match with each other ? As you can see, there is at least one startup lnk file missing in the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has several places that control what programs open on startup.

Number 2 that you mentioned, is just one place.

A list of locations: http://gladiator-antivirus.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=24610

A tool for really managing all of it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Appleoddity. Thank you gratefully for your kind answering. It makes me learn a lot.